# c++ binary file opened for input/output won't update contents

Tags: c++, windows, file, io, binary

I'm solving a c++ problem that requires updating a binary file.
Examples shows binary file is opened with ios::in ios::out ios::binary flags. I tried the following code but the binary file won't update on windows OS.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printFileContent() {
    ifstream inFile ("test.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (inFile) {
        int data;
        inFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*>(&data), sizeof(int));
        cout << data << endl;
    }
    inFile.close();
}

void createFile() {
    ofstream outFile ("test.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (outFile) {
        int data = 5;
        outFile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*>(&data), sizeof(int));
    }
    outFile.close();
}

void updateFileContent(){
    fstream ioFile ("test.bin", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (ioFile) {
        int data;
        ioFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*>(&data), sizeof(int)); // Read value
        data++; // Update value
        ioFile.seekg(-sizeof(int), ios::cur); // Seek original position
        ioFile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*>(&data), sizeof(int)); // Write new value
    }
    ioFile.close(); 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    createFile();
    printFileContent();
    updateFileContent();
    printFileContent();
    return 0;
}
```

The program outputs 5 but it should output 6. I've tried the same in Mac OS and it works fine.
I've tested my code on this website (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) and it outputs 6.

I think it is a windows related issue. Does anyone know why could this happen?.

My windows version is 20H2(OS compilation 19042.867).

Comment: Works fine on my Windows. Maybe try using `seekp` instead of `seekg`. You are supposed to manipulate the write position with `seekp`.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question m but you don’t need those calls to `close()` on the two stream objects. The destructor will do that.

Comment: Have you tried printing an error when opening the file fails? Do you have permission to create files in the directory the program is running in? An antivirus scanner or other background process may be locking the file and preventing opening it

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried seekp, but the file won't update.
I tried printing errors when opening the files, it works fine, the file gets created, the contents are saved, I can read the contents. I just can't update the content.

Comment: See if there's another test.bin that you're writing to, my guess is that you're just looking at the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

sorry a can't leave comment so this is a comment .

what happens if you write :

```
date = date + 1;
```

or

```
date += 1;
```

instead of :

```
date++;
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question or provide a solution, it's more like a suggestion. Please use the comment section instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32425251)